# difference between translational and dynamic translation equilibrium

Tags: vectors, equilibrium

What is the difference between translation equilibrium and dynamic translational equilibrium ?

Also what is the difference between rotational and dynamic rotational equilibrium ?

## definitions  :

#### Translational equilibrium :

> A body is said to be in translational equilibrium if it is at rest, or is moving at constant speed in a straight line.

#### Rotational equilibrium

> A body is said to be in rotational equilibrium if it is rotating at constant angular speed about a fixed axis.

Comment: Well, the only place where I have heard the term **Dynamic Equilibrium** is while studying Chemical Equilibrium in chemistry. I don't think it's used in Physics.

Comment: However it might be used to differentiate between two types where A) The body is at rest, B) The body is moving/rotating with uniform speed/angular speed.